# Multiple conditions are not working in conditionalPanel - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I am trying to add multiple conditions in **conditionalPanel**, both the outputs are not showing. If i am keeping either one then working.

Working with one condition-

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tab == 1",
      selectInput(
```

Not working with two conditions-

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tab == 1 && input.tab == 3",
      selectInput(
```

RStudio 2022.02.1 Build 461
R version 4.1.3
Package shiny version 1.7.1

I am expecting the output** selectInput()** to show in **tabpanel** 1 and 3.

I tried using

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tab !== 2",
      selectInput(
```

but showing **selectInput()** in **tabpanel **2 which I don't required.

Also tried

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tab == 1" && "input.tab == 3",
      selectInput(
```

but showing Shiny application failed

Comment: If you want the widget to appear in tabs 1 and 3 but not 2 (which is what I assume from your comment "showing selectInput() in **tabpanel **2 which I don't required"), then you need OR in your condition, not AND.  So  `condition = "input.tab == 1 || input.tab == 3"`, not `condition = "input.tab == 1 && input.tab == 3"`.